# Javadoc malformed locale name

Tags: locale, javadoc, malformed

I'm trying to generate Javadoc for my program but for some reason I can't seem to get rid of this error and I can't find an explanation anywhere. The issue is not just with the -author tag, even though it only states that as the error. When I remove author it just states -tag right underneath as the error. It states that I have a malformed locale name.
Here's what my documentation looks like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/glmKz.gif

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sM2E.gif